# Task :device_info:checkDebugUnitTestAarMetadata FAILED

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Problem occur when i upgrade Android Studio to Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2. Before that i can build & sync gradel. It say this when sync the gradle

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info:checkDebugUnitTestAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

```
 Dependency 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher.
 Compilation target for module ':device_info' is 'android-29'
```

Already change the targetSdkVersion & compileSdkVersion to 33 in the ../android/app/built.gradle but still same problem. Run successfully on android and ios simulator - flutter run. Problem occur when open in Android Studio..Please help